Make colors vary smoothly over a rapidly varying unstructured-grid 3D plot
I've got a 3D datafile with highly oscillating data (already sorted with zsort :),
 0   51  0.2
 0   58  0.3
 0   60  0.3
 0   60.1    0.4
 0   61  0.4
 0   62  0.5
 0   63  0.4
 0   63.1    0.5
 0   64  0.1
 0   64.1    0.3
 0   65  0.2
 0   68  0.5
 0   69  0.5
 0   70  0.5
 0   72  0.2
 0   72.1    0.3
 0   73  0.3
 0   73.1    0.1
 0   73.2    0.3
 0   74  0.3
 0   74.1    0.3
 0   75  0.1
 0   75.1    0.9
 0   76  0.2
 0   76.1    0.7
 0   76.2    0.9
 0   77  0.4
 0   79  0.2
 0   81  0.1
 0   81.1    0.2
 0   81.2    0.2
 0   81.3    0.2
 0   81.4    0.1
 0   83  0.1
 0   83.1    0.3
 0   84  0.4
 0.1     41  0.3
 0.1     46  0.5
 0.1     47  0.1
 0.1     53  0.3
 0.1     53.1    0.5
 0.1     57  0.5
 0.1     59  0.3
 0.1     61  0.3
 0.1     61.1    0.1
 0.1     61.2    -0.1
 0.1     62  0.3
 0.1     62.1    0.1
 0.1     62.2    0.1
 0.1     63  -0.3
 0.1     64  0.2
 0.1     64.1    0.6
 0.1     64.2    -0.1
 0.1     65  0.2
 0.1     65.1    0.1
 0.1     65.2    0.8
 0.1     65.3    0.9
 0.1     67  0.4
 0.1     68  0.3
 0.1     69  0.2
 0.1     70  0.3
 0.1     70.1    0.1
 0.1     71  0.1
 0.1     71.1    0.1
 0.1     72  0.2
 0.1     73  0.2
 0.1     73.1    0
 0.1     73.2    0.6
 0.1     73.3    0.3
 0.1     73.4    0.2
 0.1     75  0.4
 0.1     78  0.8
 0.1     78.1    0.2
 0.1     78.2    0.8
 0.1     79  0.5
 0.1     79.1    0.4
 0.1     82  0
 0.1     83  0.5
 0.2     34  0.2
 0.2     39  0.6
 0.2     42  0.5
 0.2     43  0.6
 0.2     49  0.4
 0.2     49.1    0.4
 0.2     50  0.7
 0.2     54  0.4
 0.2     54.1    0.6
 0.2     58  0.4
 0.2     58.1    0.1
 0.2     59  0
 0.2     60  0.6
 0.2     63  0.2
 0.2     63.1    0.5
 0.2     63.2    0.3
 0.2     64  -0.2
 0.2     64.1    0
 0.2     67  0.5
 0.2     69  0.5
 0.2     69.1    0.3
 0.2     71  0.2
 0.2     71.1    0
 0.2     71.2    0.1
 0.2     72  -0.1
 0.2     72.1    0.2
 0.2     74  -0.1
 0.2     75  0.2
 0.2     76  0.2
 0.2     77  0.4
 0.2     79  0.2
 0.2     79.1    0.2
 0.2     81  0.2
 0.2     81.1    0.3
 0.3     35  0.1
 0.3     37  0.2
 0.3     41  0.8
 0.3     46  0.4
 0.3     51  0.7
 0.3     53  0.7
 0.3     54  0.2
 0.3     57  0.1
 0.3     58  0.6
 0.3     59  0.5
 0.3     61  0.3
 0.3     61.1    0.1
 0.3     62  0.5
 0.3     62.1    0.8
 0.3     62.2    0.3
 0.3     63  0.3
 0.3     63.1    0.3
 0.3     64  0.8
 0.3     64.1    0.3
 0.3     64.2    0.4
 0.3     69  0.6
 0.3     70  0.3
 0.3     72  0.1
 0.3     74  0
 0.3     76  0.3
 0.3     76.1    0.1
 0.3     79  0.3
 0.3     80  0.1
 0.3     80.1    0.1
 0.3     81  0.3
 0.3     81.1    0.2
 0.3     83  0
 0.4     34  0.6
 0.4     34.1    0.5
 0.4     36  0.2
 0.4     39  0.6
 0.4     41  -0.1
 0.4     42  0.3
 0.4     43  0.5
 0.4     48  0.7
 0.4     49  0.6
 0.4     52  0.8
 0.4     52.1    0.1
 0.4     54  0.7
 0.4     58  0.8
 0.4     60  0
 0.4     61  0.1
 0.4     63  -0.1
 0.4     63.1    0
 0.4     66  0.7
 0.4     67  0.2
 0.4     67.1    0.3
 0.4     70  0.4
 0.4     70.1    0.3
 0.4     71  0.1
 0.4     74  0.2
 0.5     33  0.6
 0.5     34  0.1
 0.5     35  0.3
 0.5     46  0.1
 0.5     47  0.4
 0.5     53  0.8
 0.5     55  0.3
 0.5     58  0.1
 0.5     59  0.2
 0.5     59.1    0.1
 0.5     60  0.8
 0.5     60.1    -0.1
 0.5     61  0.4
 0.5     61.1    0.3
 0.5     62  0.2
 0.5     63  0
 0.5     64  0.2
 0.5     67  0.2
 0.5     68  0.2
 0.5     69  0.2
 0.5     70  0.1
 0.5     72  0.1
 0.5     73  0.1
 0.5     76  0.3
 0.5     76.1    0.2
 0.5     79  0.2
 0.5     79.1    0.2
 0.5     80  0.8
 0.5     84  0.1
 0.5     84.1    0.4
 0.6     20  0.7
 0.6     22  0.8
 0.6     30  0.4
 0.6     30.1    0.7
 0.6     31  0.6
 0.6     35  0.9
 0.6     35.1    0.9
 0.6     37  0.5
 0.6     38  0.2
 0.6     39  0.6
 0.6     42  0.3
 0.6     43  0.3
 0.6     46  1
 0.6     47  0.6
 0.6     49  0.2
 0.6     49.1    0.1
 0.6     51  0.9
 0.6     51.1    0.2
 0.6     54  0.9
 0.6     55  1.1
 0.6     59  0.6
 0.6     61  0.6
 0.6     62  0.6
 0.6     62.1    0.6
 0.6     62.2    0.1
 0.6     64  0.9
 0.6     65  0.2
 0.6     65.1    0.5
 0.6     66  0.2
 0.6     75  0.4
 0.6     81  0.1
 0.6     81.1    0.1
 0.6     81.2    0.7
 0.6     83  0.5
 0.7     23  0.4
 0.7     24  0.9
 0.7     26  1.1
 0.7     27  0.7
 0.7     33  0.7
 0.7     33.1    0
 0.7     34  0.3
 0.7     36  0.1
 0.7     37  0.9
 0.7     37.1    0.6
 0.7     40  0.5
 0.7     46  0.1
 0.7     46.1    0.8
 0.7     46.2    0.5
 0.7     48  0.7
 0.7     49  0.5
 0.7     50  0.9
 0.7     51  0.8
 0.7     52  0.8
 0.7     52.1    0.5
 0.7     54  0.2
 0.7     54.1    0
 0.7     55  0.9
 0.7     56  0.6
 0.7     56.1    0.6
 0.7     56.2    0.8
 0.7     56.3    0.1
 0.7     57  0.4
 0.7     58  0
 0.7     59  1
 0.7     59.1    0
 0.7     60  0.1
 0.7     62  0.2
 0.7     68  0.1
 0.7     68.1    0.2
 0.7     71  0.4
 0.7     71.1    0.5
 0.7     72  0.2
 0.7     77  0.2
 0.7     81  0.2
 0.7     83  0.1
 0.8     21  1
 0.8     28  0.9
 0.8     28.1    0.1
 0.8     29  0.8
 0.8     32  0.1
 0.8     34  1.1
 0.8     37  0.1
 0.8     38  0
 0.8     39  0.7
 0.8     45  0.2
 0.8     47  0.1
 0.8     47.1    0.3
 0.8     47.2    0.7
 0.8     48  0.2
 0.8     50  0.2
 0.8     50.1    0.8
 0.8     52  0.2
 0.8     52.1    0.2
 0.8     54  0.2
 0.8     58  1
 0.8     60  0.2
 0.8     62  0.5
 0.8     64  0.2
 0.8     64.1    0.2
 0.8     65  0.6
 0.8     65.1    0.2
 0.8     65.2    0.2
 0.8     65.3    0.3
 0.8     66  0
 0.8     68  0.4
 0.8     71  0
 0.8     71.1    0.4
 0.8     73  0.3
 0.8     76  0.3
 0.8     77  0.2
 0.8     77.1    0.1
 0.8     77.2    0.1
 0.8     78  0.3
 0.8     81  0.2
 0.8     81.1    0.3
 0.8     84  0.2
 0.9     21  0.9
 0.9     21.1    1.1
 0.9     22  0.8
 0.9     24  0.4
 0.9     26  0.9
 0.9     29  0.7
 0.9     32  0.9
 0.9     32.1    0.7
 0.9     35  0.7
 0.9     36  1.4
 0.9     38  0
 0.9     41  0
 0.9     43  1
 0.9     44  0.7
 0.9     54  0.2
 0.9     56  0.7
 0.9     57  1.2
 0.9     60  0.3
 0.9     60.1    1
 0.9     61  0.2
 0.9     62  1.1
 0.9     62.1    0.3
 0.9     62.2    0.4
 0.9     64  0.3
 0.9     64.1    0.2
 0.9     67  0.2
 0.9     70  0.2
 0.9     70.1    0.5
 0.9     72  0.3
 0.9     76  0.2
 0.9     77  0.1
 0.9     78  0.1
 0.9     78.1    0.3
 0.9     80  0
 0.9     80.1    0.3
 1   24  0.3
 1   25  0.7
 1   30  0.6
 1   30.1    0.9
 1   34  0.9
 1   34.1    0.7
 1   35  0.9
 1   36  0.6
 1   37  0.2
 1   38  0.6
 1   39  1
 1   40  0
 1   40.1    1
 1   43  0.6
 1   48  0.5
 1   48.1    1.1
 1   50  0.1
 1   51  0.8
 1   52  1.1
 1   53  0.1
 1   54  0.4
 1   55  0.1
 1   58  0.2
 1   60  0.2
 1   60.1    0.3
 1   61  0
 1   61.1    0.9
 1   62  0.1
 1   64  0.4
 1   65  0.2
 1   66  0.3
 1   68  0.5
 1   69  0.9
 1   70  1.5
 1   71  0
 1   72  0.1
 1   72.1    0.2
 1   73  0.2
 1   73.1    1.1
 1   73.2    0.2
 1   74  0.2
 1   74.1    0.3
 1   76  0.2
 1   77  0.4
 1   77.1    0.2
 1   77.2    0.2
 1   81  0.5
 1   85  0.4
 1.1     22  1.2
 1.1     23  0.7
 1.1     23.1    0.5
 1.1     24  0.7
 1.1     24.1    0.8
 1.1     26  0.9
 1.1     26.1    1.2
 1.1     33  1.3
 1.1     34  1.2
 1.1     36  0.7
 1.1     40  0.6
 1.1     42  0
 1.1     46  0.4
 1.1     48  0.2
 1.1     49  0.1
 1.1     52  0.1
 1.1     55  0.2
 1.1     57  1.2
 1.1     59  1.4
 1.1     60  1.5
 1.1     60.1    0
 1.1     61  0.1
 1.1     61.1    -0.1
 1.1     61.2    1
 1.1     62  0.2
 1.1     64  0.1
 1.1     64.1    0.2
 1.1     64.2    0.2
 1.1     64.3    0.1
 1.1     65  0.7
 1.1     65.1    0.4
 1.1     66  0.9
 1.1     66.1    0.3
 1.1     66.2    0.2
 1.1     67  0.2
 1.1     67.1    0.1
 1.1     68  0.4
 1.1     71  0.5
 1.1     71.1    0.1
 1.1     71.2    0.2
 1.1     75  0.2
 1.1     76  0.3
 1.1     76.1    0.4
 1.1     77  0.3
 1.1     77.1    0.4
 1.1     79  0.2
 1.2     22  1.2
 1.2     22.1    0.9
 1.2     23  1.3
 1.2     28  0
 1.2     30  0.8
 1.2     32  0
 1.2     33  0.8
 1.2     33.1    0.5
 1.2     35  0.8
 1.2     35.1    1.1
 1.2     38  0.1
 1.2     38.1    0.1
 1.2     39  1
 1.2     39.1    0.7
 1.2     39.2    0.8
 1.2     40  0.3
 1.2     42  1
 1.2     43  1.5
 1.2     44  0
 1.2     47  0.5
 1.2     47.1    0.6
 1.2     47.2    0.4
 1.2     47.3    0.2
 1.2     49  0
 1.2     49.1    0.2
 1.2     50  0
 1.2     50.1    0
 1.2     53  0.1
 1.2     53.1    1.2
 1.2     58  0.3
 1.2     58.1    0
 1.2     60  0.7
 1.2     63  0.1
 1.2     63.1    0.3
 1.2     65  0.2
 1.2     65.1    -0.1
 1.2     66  0.4
 1.2     66.1    0.1
 1.2     66.2    0.2
 1.2     67  0.2
 1.2     67.1    0.3
 1.2     69  0.1
 1.2     70  0.2
 1.2     70.1    0
 1.2     71  0.2
 1.2     75  0.1
 1.2     78  0.1
 1.2     80  0.3
 1.2     81  0
 1.2     81.1    0.2
 1.2     81.2    0.4
 1.2     82  0.3
 1.2     82.1    0.1
 1.2     83  0.1
 1.3     18  0.6
 1.3     22  0.6
 1.3     22.1    0.8
 1.3     22.2    0.6
 1.3     24  0.3
 1.3     24.1    1
 1.3     29  0.6
 1.3     30  1.2
 1.3     32  1.1
 1.3     34  0.9
 1.3     37  0.3
 1.3     37.1    0.9
 1.3     38  0.2
 1.3     41  1.4
 1.3     45  -0.1
 1.3     45.1    1.1
 1.3     45.2    1.1
 1.3     47  0.1
 1.3     52  0.5
 1.3     59  0.1
 1.3     59.1    0.2
 1.3     60  0.2
 1.3     61  0.9
 1.3     62  0.2
 1.3     63  0.1
 1.3     64  0
 1.3     65  1.1
 1.3     67  0.1
 1.3     67.1    0.2
 1.3     68  0.3
 1.3     68.1    0.1
 1.3     69  1.2
 1.3     71  0.6
 1.3     72  0.2
 1.3     73  0.2
 1.3     73.1    0.3
 1.3     74  0.1
 1.3     75  1.2
 1.3     77  0.3
 1.3     78  0.2
 1.3     79  0.2
 1.3     84  0.2
 1.4     21  1.3
 1.4     21.1    0.8
 1.4     22  0.7
 1.4     23  1.3
 1.4     28  0.5
 1.4     29  0.9
 1.4     31  1.3
 1.4     33  0.6
 1.4     35  0.1
 1.4     38  0.2
 1.4     41  0.1
 1.4     44  0.5
 1.4     46  0.2
 1.4     47  0.1
 1.4     50  0.3
 1.4     51  0
 1.4     53  0.2
 1.4     53.1    0.2
 1.4     54  0.1
 1.4     55  0.8
 1.4     57  0.2
 1.4     59  0.3
 1.4     59.1    0.2
 1.4     62  0.6
 1.4     63  1.2
 1.4     64  0.5
 1.4     65  0
 1.4     66  0.2
 1.4     67  0.5
 1.4     67.1    1.2
 1.4     69  0.6
 1.4     69.1    0.1
 1.4     71  0.3
 1.4     71.1    0.1
 1.4     73  0.1
 1.4     74  0.3
 1.4     74.1    0.4
 1.4     75  0.2
 1.4     75.1    0.3
 1.4     75.2    0.2
 1.4     75.3    0.2
 1.4     77  0.2
 1.4     77.1    0.3
 1.4     78  0.2
 1.4     78.1    0.3
 1.4     81  0.2
 1.4     83  0
 1.4     85  0.3
 1.5     20  0.6
 1.5     21  0.7
 1.5     21.1    1.1
 1.5     23  1.3
 1.5     26  0.9
 1.5     28  0.9
 1.5     32  1.2
 1.5     32.1    1.8
 1.5     33  0.3
 1.5     36  0.1
 1.5     38  0.1
 1.5     38.1    0.1
 1.5     43  0.2
 1.5     43.1    0
 1.5     44  0.5
 1.5     44.1    0.2
 1.5     44.2    0.3
 1.5     44.3    0.1
 1.5     47  0.2
 1.5     49  0.1
 1.5     52  0.1
 1.5     53  0.1
 1.5     54  0.1
 1.5     55  0.2
 1.5     56  0.3
 1.5     57  0.1
 1.5     58  0.2
 1.5     59  1.2
 1.5     61  0.3
 1.5     62  0.2
 1.5     62.1    0.3
 1.5     64  0.5
 1.5     65  0.1
 1.5     65.1    0.2
 1.5     65.2    0.4
 1.5     65.3    0.3
 1.5     66  1
 1.5     67  0.3
 1.5     69  0.3
 1.5     69.1    -0.1
 1.5     70  0.3
 1.5     74  0.3
 1.5     74.1    0.4
 1.5     74.2    0.2
 1.5     74.3    0.3
 1.5     76  0.4
 1.5     77  0.1
 1.5     79  0.2
 1.5     80  0.4
 1.5     83  0.1
 1.6     19  1
 1.6     22  0.9
 1.6     23  1
 1.6     24  1.2
 1.6     26  0.7
 1.6     29  0.9
 1.6     29.1    0.9
 1.6     30  0.1
 1.6     30.1    1.5
 1.6     32  1
 1.6     33  1
 1.6     42  0.8
 1.6     43  0.2
 1.6     43.1    1.1
 1.6     44  0.1
 1.6     48  1.2
 1.6     49  1.1
 1.6     50  -0.1
 1.6     54  0.2
 1.6     54.1    -0.1
 1.6     56  1.3
 1.6     57  0
 1.6     58  0.3
 1.6     59  0.2
 1.6     59.1    0.3
 1.6     61  0.2
 1.6     62  0
 1.6     62.1    1.2
 1.6     65  0.1
 1.6     65.1    0.8
 1.6     65.2    0.1
 1.6     66  0.2
 1.6     67  0.1
 1.6     68  0.2
 1.6     69  0.1
 1.6     70  0.1
 1.6     71  0.4
 1.6     71.1    0
 1.6     71.2    0.2
 1.6     76  1.1
 1.6     83  0.2
 1.6     84  0.4
 1.7     19  1
 1.7     24  0.9
 1.7     24.1    1.2
 1.7     25  0.5
 1.7     26  0.2
 1.7     26.1    0.9
 1.7     28  0.8
 1.7     32  0.7
 1.7     33  1.1
 1.7     38  0.7
 1.7     40  0.1
 1.7     41  0.2
 1.7     41.1    1.2
 1.7     42  0.8
 1.7     45  0.4
 1.7     46  0.1
 1.7     47  0.6
 1.7     53  0.1
 1.7     54  0.2
 1.7     54.1    1.3
 1.7     56  0.1
 1.7     61  0.1
 1.7     62  0.3
 1.7     62.1    1.2
 1.7     62.2    0.6
 1.7     63  1.3
 1.7     63.1    1.3
 1.7     65  -0.5
 1.7     65.1    0.1
 1.7     65.2    0.1
 1.7     66  0.2
 1.7     66.1    0.2
 1.7     67  0.2
 1.7     68  0.1
 1.7     69  0.6
 1.7     71  0.2
 1.7     72  0.9
 1.7     74  0.5
 1.7     76  0.5
 1.7     76.1    0.1
 1.7     78  0.8
 1.7     80  0.3
 1.7     82  0.1
 1.8     21  0.7
 1.8     22  1.2
 1.8     22.1    0.8
 1.8     23  1.4
 1.8     23.1    0.6
 1.8     26  0.9
 1.8     30  0.1
 1.8     31  0.1
 1.8     32  0.9
 1.8     35  0.3
 1.8     39  1.2
 1.8     41  0.2
 1.8     42  0.2
 1.8     42.1    0.2
 1.8     45  0
 1.8     45.1    0.1
 1.8     45.2    -0.1
 1.8     48  0.7
 1.8     56  0.6
 1.8     56.1    0.5
 1.8     57  0.1
 1.8     57.1    0.2
 1.8     58  0
 1.8     59  0.2
 1.8     59.1    0.1
 1.8     59.2    0.9
 1.8     60  0.3
 1.8     60.1    0.1
 1.8     60.2    0.2
 1.8     61  -0.1
 1.8     63  0.2
 1.8     64  0.1
 1.8     65  0.2
 1.8     65.1    0.2
 1.8     65.2    0.2
 1.8     66  0.2
 1.8     66.1    0.6
 1.8     66.2    0.2
 1.8     66.3    0.1
 1.8     66.4    0.2
 1.8     67  0.2
 1.8     68  0.1
 1.8     68.1    0.1
 1.8     70  0.2
 1.8     70.1    0
 1.8     71  0.1
 1.8     71.1    0.1
 1.8     72  0.1
 1.8     72.1    0.3
 1.8     75  0.2
 1.8     75.1    0.3
 1.8     77  0.4
 1.8     79  0.4
 1.8     83  0.1
 1.9     20  0.7
 1.9     23  1.5
 1.9     30  0.8
 1.9     31  0.9
 1.9     34  0.2
 1.9     36  0.1
 1.9     38  0.5
 1.9     38.1    1.1
 1.9     39  0.3
 1.9     40  0
 1.9     41  0.6
 1.9     44  1.3
 1.9     45  0.1
 1.9     46  0.3
 1.9     47  0.1
 1.9     50  0.2
 1.9     50.1    0.5
 1.9     53  0.4
 1.9     53.1    1.1
 1.9     54  0.2
 1.9     58  0.9
 1.9     58.1    0.2
 1.9     58.2    0.2
 1.9     59  0.3
 1.9     59.1    0.1
 1.9     61  0.1
 1.9     62  0.3
 1.9     62.1    0.3
 1.9     63  0.1
 1.9     66  0.2
 1.9     67  0.4
 1.9     68  0.1
 1.9     70  0.2
 1.9     70.1    0.3
 1.9     70.2    0.2
 1.9     70.3    0.1
 1.9     72  0.2
 1.9     72.1    0.2
 1.9     73  0.1
 1.9     74  0.3
 1.9     74.1    0.3
 1.9     75  0.8
 1.9     83  0
 1.9     84  0.4
 1.9     85  0.3
 2   20  1
 2   27  0.4
 2   29  1.4
 2   31  0.8
 2   32  1
 2   32.1    0.3
 2   33  0.3
 2   36  1.2
 2   36.1    0.1
 2   37  0.1
 2   38  0.2
 2   39  0.5
 2   40  0.6
 2   40.1    1.5
 2   43  -0.1
 2   44  0.2
 2   45  0.2
 2   46  -0.1
 2   52  0.1
 2   55  0.5
 2   56  0.5
 2   57  0.2
 2   58  1.1
 2   58.1    0.3
 2   59  0.4
 2   62  0.4
 2   62.1    0
 2   63  0.2
 2   63.1    0.7
 2   64  0.3
 2   65  0.1
 2   65.1    0.1
 2   66  0.2
 2   68  0.2
 2   69  1.2
 2   69.1    0.1
 2   71  0.1
 2   71.1    0.3
 2   71.2    0.1
 2   72  0.2
 2   74  0.2
 2   74.1    1.2
 2   74.2    0.4
 2   74.3    0.2
 2   77  0.1
 2   80  0.2
 2   80.1    0.1
 2   81  0.1
 2.1     21  0.8
 2.1     21.1    0.9
 2.1     25  0.9
 2.1     27  0.9
 2.1     28  0.9
 2.1     29  1.2
 2.1     30  0.9
 2.1     30.1    0.4
 2.1     32  0.8
 2.1     33  0.8
 2.1     34  0.2
 2.1     34.1    0.1
 2.1     40  0.6
 2.1     40.1    0.3
 2.1     42  1
 2.1     43  1.2
 2.1     43.1    1.2
 2.1     44  0.2
 2.1     47  0.2
 2.1     49  0.2
 2.1     52  0.4
 2.1     53  1.3
 2.1     53.1    0.4
 2.1     53.2    0.3
 2.1     55  0.1
 2.1     56  0.1
 2.1     58  0.4
 2.1     59  0.2
 2.1     60  0.1
 2.1     65  0.2
 2.1     66  0.3
 2.1     66.1    0.2
 2.1     66.2    0.3
 2.1     67  0.3
 2.1     68  0.1
 2.1     68.1    0.4
 2.1     69  0.4
 2.1     70  0.9
 2.1     70.1    0.3
 2.1     70.2    -0.1
 2.1     73  0
 2.1     73.1    0.3
 2.1     73.2    0.3
 2.1     73.3    0.1
 2.1     74  0.1
 2.1     75  0.2
 2.1     76  0.5
 2.1     76.1    0.2
 2.1     78  0.4
 2.1     79  0.4
 2.1     79.1    0.4
 2.1     80  0.2
 2.2     18  0.7
 2.2     21  0.9
 2.2     29  0.7
 2.2     29.1    1.1
 2.2     31  0.1
 2.2     32  0.1
 2.2     33  0.3
 2.2     36  0
 2.2     36.1    1.1
 2.2     37  0.9
 2.2     41  0.8
 2.2     41.1    1.5
 2.2     42  0.1
 2.2     44  0.1
 2.2     45  1
 2.2     48  0.3
 2.2     54  0.2
 2.2     54.1    1
 2.2     55  0.2
 2.2     56  0.1
 2.2     56.1    0.1
 2.2     61  0
 2.2     64  0.2
 2.2     64.1    0.2
 2.2     65  0.1
 2.2     66  0.2
 2.2     66.1    0.2
 2.2     67  0.2
 2.2     68  0.1
 2.2     68.1    0.1
 2.2     69  0.1
 2.2     69.1    0.3
 2.2     71  0.2
 2.2     72  0.2
 2.2     73  0.5
 2.2     73.1    0.2
 2.2     74  0.3
 2.2     75  0.9
 2.3     19  0.7
 2.3     37  0.9
 2.3     37.1    0.1
 2.3     37.2    0.2
 2.3     40  0.2
 2.3     41  0.1
 2.3     42  1.2
 2.3     44  0.2
 2.3     45  0.6
 2.3     46  0.2
 2.3     46.1    0.2
 2.3     47  0.5
 2.3     49  0.4
 2.3     50  0.1
 2.3     50.1    0.3
 2.3     54  0.1
 2.3     54.1    0.1
 2.3     55  -0.1
 2.3     56  0.2
 2.3     56.1    0.9
 2.3     56.2    0.2
 2.3     57  0.7
 2.3     57.1    1.4
 2.3     60  0.3
 2.3     61  0.3
 2.3     62  0.2
 2.3     64  0.1
 2.3     64.1    0.3
 2.3     65  0.2
 2.3     66  0.2
 2.3     67  0.3
 2.3     67.1    0.2
 2.3     68  0.5
 2.3     71  0.3
 2.3     71.1    0.3
 2.3     73  0.2
 2.3     74  0.2
 2.3     74.1    0.2
 2.4     22  1.6
 2.4     27  0.7
 2.4     27.1    1
 2.4     27.2    0.1
 2.4     30  0.1
 2.4     37  0.1
 2.4     38  0.7
 2.4     40  0.2
 2.4     41  0.2
 2.4     42  0.2
 2.4     47  1.7
 2.4     51  -0.2
 2.4     52  0.1
 2.4     54  0.2
 2.4     54.1    0.1
 2.4     54.2    0
 2.4     54.3    0.2
 2.4     55  0.5
 2.4     55.1    0.1
 2.4     57  0.2
 2.4     58  0.2
 2.4     59  0.2
 2.4     63  0.1
 2.4     64  0.2
 2.4     65  0.2
 2.4     66  0.2
 2.4     66.1    0.2
 2.4     66.2    0.5
 2.4     67  0.1
 2.4     67.1    0.2
 2.4     68  0.3
 2.4     70  0.3
 2.4     71  0.1
 2.4     75  0.4
 2.4     75.1    0
 2.5     23  0.7
 2.5     26  0.1
 2.5     27  1
 2.5     29  0.8
 2.5     30  0.4
 2.5     31  0.5
 2.5     32  0.9
 2.5     33  1.1
 2.5     34  1.1
 2.5     41  1
 2.5     42  0.1
 2.5     45  0.1
 2.5     45.1    1.3
 2.5     45.2    0.7
 2.5     46  0.1
 2.5     48  1.3
 2.5     48.1    0.5
 2.5     48.2    0.5
 2.5     49  1
 2.5     58  0.2
 2.5     58.1    0.1
 2.5     61  0.2
 2.5     61.1    0.1
 2.5     63  0.2
 2.5     63.1    0.2
 2.5     64  0.2
 2.5     65  0.4
 2.5     66  0.2
 2.5     66.1    0.2
 2.5     67  0.2
 2.5     70  0.3
 2.5     70.1    0.4
 2.5     70.2    0.2
 2.5     70.3    0.2
 2.5     70.4    0.3
 2.5     70.5    0.6
 2.5     73  0.2
 2.5     73.1    0.1
 2.5     73.2    0.3
 2.5     75  0.2
 2.6     22  1
 2.6     24  0.8
 2.6     29  0.5
 2.6     31  0.3
 2.6     31.1    0.5
 2.6     38  0.7
 2.6     38.1    0.1
 2.6     42  0.2
 2.6     43  0.2
 2.6     45  0.1
 2.6     54  0.4
 2.6     54.1    0.2
 2.6     60  0
 2.6     60.1    0.4
 2.6     61  0.2
 2.6     67  0.1
 2.6     68  0.4
 2.6     70  1.2
 2.6     70.1    0.1
 2.6     72  0.1
 2.6     75  0.2
 2.6     79  0.1
 2.7     27  0.7
 2.7     27.1    0.8
 2.7     30  0.3
 2.7     33  1
 2.7     33.1    -0.2
 2.7     38  0.9
 2.7     42  0.7
 2.7     42.1    0.7
 2.7     48  1
 2.7     48.1    0
 2.7     49  0.9
 2.7     53  0.1
 2.7     55  0.4
 2.7     55.1    0.2
 2.7     56  0.1
 2.7     58  0.3
 2.7     60  0.2
 2.7     61  0.5
 2.7     62  0.2
 2.7     64  0.8
 2.7     66  0.1
 2.7     68  0.2
 2.7     69  0.2
 2.7     69.1    0.3
 2.7     72  0.3
 2.7     72.1    0.3
 2.7     73  0.3
 2.7     74  0.2
 2.7     75  0.1
 2.8     17  0.6
 2.8     23  0.4
 2.8     24  0.6
 2.8     27  1.6
 2.8     28  0.6
 2.8     29  0.6
 2.8     31  0.9
 2.8     32  0.9
 2.8     36  0.5
 2.8     38  0.1
 2.8     40  0.6
 2.8     40.1    0.5
 2.8     53  0.4
 2.8     54  0.1
 2.8     54.1    0.2
 2.8     56  0.2
 2.8     56.1    0.2
 2.8     58  0.1
 2.8     58.1    0.7
 2.8     61  1.1
 2.8     64  0
 2.8     65  0.1
 2.8     65.1    0.1
 2.8     68  0.5
 2.8     74  0.8
 2.8     77  0.3
 2.9     19  0.3
 2.9     32  0.1
 2.9     32.1    0.7
 2.9     34  0
 2.9     36  0.1
 2.9     37  0.8
 2.9     38  1
 2.9     38.1    0.8
 2.9     40  1
 2.9     45  1
 2.9     45.1    0.2
 2.9     46  0.3
 2.9     47  0.7
 2.9     53  0.4
 2.9     53.1    0
 2.9     54  0.4
 2.9     55  0.3
 2.9     56  0.1
 2.9     56.1    0.2
 2.9     60  -0.2
 2.9     61  0
 2.9     62  0.2
 2.9     62.1    0.1
 2.9     63  0.2
 2.9     67  0
 2.9     68  0.3
 2.9     73  0.3
 2.9     73.1    0.2
 3   22  1
 3   24  0.1
 3   24.1    0.4
 3   29  0.6
 3   34  0.2
 3   39  0.2
 3   41  0.4
 3   41.1    0.7
 3   42  1
 3   42.1    0.8
 3   56  0.2
 3   65  0.2
 3   69  0.3
 3   71  0.5
 3   78  0.2
 3   79  0.1
 3.1     17  0.8
 3.1     18  0.5
 3.1     22  1
 3.1     32  0.2
 3.1     32.1    0.9
 3.1     38  0.3
 3.1     44  0.5
 3.1     46  0.2
 3.1     53  0.1
 3.1     56  0.1
 3.1     56.1    0.2
 3.1     64  0
 3.1     70  0.4
 3.1     72  0.6
 3.1     76  0.2
 3.2     18  0.7
 3.2     21  0.3
 3.2     22  1.1
 3.2     36  1.2
 3.2     38  0.6
 3.2     38.1    0.8
 3.2     42  0
 3.2     46  -0.1
 3.2     46.1    0.1
 3.2     47  0.3
 3.2     47.1    0.5
 3.2     47.2    0.5
 3.2     50  0.5
 3.2     58  0.1
 3.2     60  0.5
 3.2     65  0.8
 3.2     67  0
 3.2     69  0.9
 3.2     73  1
 3.2     74  0
 3.2     77  0.2
 3.3     17  0.6
 3.3     19  1.5
 3.3     23  1
 3.3     25  0.3
 3.3     28  0.7
 3.3     35  0.5
 3.3     35.1    0.6
 3.3     52  0.2
 3.3     62  0.1
 3.3     63  0.4
 3.3     64  0
 3.3     64.1    0.3
 3.3     64.2    0.1
 3.3     73  0.2
 3.3     74  0.3
 3.3     79  0.2
 3.4     18  0.6
 3.4     20  0.1
 3.4     34  0.6
 3.4     38  0.2
 3.4     38.1    0.6
 3.4     40  0.2
 3.4     41  0.8
 3.4     56  0.7
 3.5     22  1
 3.5     30  0.4
 3.5     30.1    0.4
 3.5     32  0.3
 3.5     34  0.4
 3.5     38  0.8
 3.5     38.1    0.2
 3.5     41  0.5
 3.5     49  0.3
 3.5     54  0.1
 3.5     69  0.2
 3.5     71  0.3
 3.5     74  0.4
 3.6     24  1.1
 3.6     25  0.7
 3.6     32  0.4
 3.6     42  0
 3.6     46  0.2
 3.6     57  0.2
 3.7     22  1.1
 3.7     22.1    0.8
 3.7     23  0.1
 3.7     23.1    1.1
 3.7     27  0.7
 3.7     30  0.6
 3.7     34  0.1
 3.7     35  0.1
 3.7     40  0.9
 3.7     44  0.2
 3.7     45  0.4
 3.7     46  0.5
 3.7     49  0.4
 3.7     50  0.1
 3.7     51  0.8
 3.7     66  0.4
 3.8     18  0.3
 3.8     22  1.4
 3.8     23  0.5
 3.8     24  0.7
 3.8     24.1    0.5
 3.8     28  0.3
 3.8     28.1    0.6
 3.8     37  1.1
 3.8     38  0.6
 3.8     39  0.6
 3.8     44  0.8
 3.8     46  0
 3.8     65  0.1
 3.9     17  1.4
 3.9     27  0.6
 3.9     31  1
 3.9     32  0.5
 3.9     34  0.3
 3.9     54  0.1
 3.9     61  0.2
 3.9     64  0.3
 3.9     66  0.2
 3.9     66.1    0.2
 3.9     67  0
 4   22  1
 4   28  0.6
 4   29  0.4
 4   30  0.2
 4   31  0.6
 4   32  0.1
 4   45  0.5
 4   56  0.2
 4   65  0.1
 4   73  0.3
 4.1     16  1.3
 4.1     23  1.1
 4.1     25  0.6
 4.1     26  0.6
 4.1     28  0.7
 4.1     32  0.4
 4.1     32.1    0.6
 4.1     33  0.5
 4.1     41  0.2
 4.1     42  0.7
 4.1     43  0.2
 4.1     45  0.3
 4.1     64  0.2
 4.1     65  0
 4.2     26  0.5
 4.2     27  0.4
 4.2     27.1    0.7
 4.2     27.2    0.3
 4.2     31  0.5
 4.2     33  0.3
 4.2     33.1    0.5
 4.2     36  0.3
 4.2     38  0.1
 4.2     51  0.3
 4.2     62  0.9
 4.2     70  0.5
 4.3     17  1.2
 4.3     27  0.6
 4.3     29  0.4
 4.3     29.1    0.7
 4.3     33  0.4
 4.3     35  0.2
 4.3     38  0.9
 4.3     41  0.6
 4.3     42  0.6
 4.3     45  0.1
 4.3     63  0.1
 4.3     71  0.1
 4.4     21  0.9
 4.4     24  0.4
 4.4     29  0.2
 4.4     33  0.6
 4.4     35  0.1
 4.4     42  0
 4.4     43  1
 4.4     45  0.5
 4.4     62  0.1
 4.5     23  0.8
 4.5     29  0.6
 4.5     35  0.3
 4.5     38  1.2
 4.5     39  0.2
 4.5     40  -0.3
 4.5     42  0.6
 4.5     42.1    0.6
 4.6     22  1.1
 4.6     25  0.5
 4.6     25.1    0.6
 4.6     32  0.6
 4.6     34  0.7
 4.6     35  0.6
 4.6     37  0.4
 4.6     41  0.7
 4.7     27  0.7
 4.7     32  0.6
 4.7     33  0.5
 4.7     37  0.3
 4.8     23  0.9
 4.8     25  0.6
 4.8     26  1.1
 4.8     34  0.7
 4.8     34.1    0.6
 4.8     37  0.2
 4.8     38  1.1
 4.8     47  0.7
 4.8     57  0.5
 4.8     64  0.4
 4.9     21  0.9
 4.9     23  1
 4.9     26  0.5
 4.9     27  0.5
 4.9     28  0.3
 4.9     28.1    0.2
 4.9     33  0.7
 4.9     33.1    0.5
 4.9     34  0.5
 4.9     40  0.7
 4.9     44  0.5
 5   30  0.4
 5   41  0.2
 5   48  0.7
 5.1     27  0.5
 5.1     33  0.6
 5.1     43  0.1
 5.1     45  0.5
 5.2     30  0.7
 5.2     31  0.7
 5.2     35  0.6
 5.2     38  1.1
 5.2     47  0.5
 5.3     30  0.5
 5.3     32  0.4
 5.4     30  0.6
 5.4     32  0.3
 5.4     38  0.9
 5.5     32  0.7
 5.5     39  0.9
 5.6     38  0.8
 5.6     41  -0.7
 5.7     21  -0.4
 5.7     33  0.3
 5.7     37  0.9
 5.8     64  0.1
 5.9     34  0.3
 6   26  0.9
 6.5     61  -0.1

The (x,y) values define an unstructured grid. As a result I have had to use set dgrid3d to build a regular grid by interpolation, since gnuplot does not perform triangulations for the time being.
The data being so oscillating, a good resolution requires the use of a very dense grid. I've tried set dgrid3d 512,512 and set dgrid3d 900,900 and splotted the file with pm3d, see below. In the latter case, resolution is better but as you see, there are still color jumps: is there a way to make the colors vary smoothly along the whole plot ? (only in less-rapidly-oscillating areas, the colors do vary smoothly). I have also projected the 3D plot onto the (x,y) plane with set contour and then a thousand contours with set cntrparam levels, to have a better resolution, as well as set palette maxcolors 1024 but that does not change anything. If anyone could give me a hint...
512x512-point grid with dgrid3d

900x900-point grid with dgrid3d


Regridding it with a very small gaussian blur applied afterwards might make things just smooth enough to deceive the eye. Personally I prefer a 2D heat map for this sort of thing. I find the 3D mountains floating above it very distracting and unhelpful for interpreting the data. YMMV.

You mean something like set dgrid3d 900,900 gauss 1?

I agree with @MartinBrown  3D maybe looks "nice" but you might hide some data, e.g. if there is a large peak in front of a smaller peak from a certain viewing angle. And with your current representation 3D floating over 2D you are definitely hiding a part of 2D data. I also would prefer a 2D heatmap. Maybe you want to check this about triangulation with gnuplot, but be warned, it's cumbersome.

It certainly hides a bit of the 2D heatmap, but in fact this image is rotating (I couldn't upload it since it's 25MB weight) so it's all well visible. I understand that for the 3D plot resolution, a smoother variation of colors is not possible. Triangulation would be great and I have tried your 2Dscript, but for 1500 points (as is my case) it is extremely slow. I know matplotlib can do the job at the blink of an eye but overall I prefer gnuplot much more. Let's hope gnuplot will make it in the near future both for 2D & 3D Delaunay triangulation.

@user24353751 I don't think that gnuplot will implement Delaunay triangulation soon, probably never. What I hear is that gnuplot wants to be a plotting tool, not a data processing or preparation tool. Well, you could try qhull as external tool to quickly get some Delaunay triangulation output format which gnuplot can read (maybe after some modifications via a gnuplot script).

@user24353751 how does your data look like? How many datapoints? Could you maybe provide the data for testing?

There we go, at the very beginning of my question. Datapoints... 1438.

I don't really see how Delaunay triangulation is going to help in this case. A Gaussian kernel to dgrid3d seems a better option. It depends on the physical significance of the point values.  Are they samples?  Independent events?  Should nearby points be averaged or summed?
For what it's worth you can do the triangulation in gnuplot 6. This mode is currently undocumented, as the implementation is only as only as complete as needed to serve as a step on the way to generating concave hulls.  The plot style with polygons takes the color from the first vertex of the triangle. A more complete implementation could allow other options like averaging the vertex z values.
set style fill solid border lc "black"
plot 'DATA' using 1:2:3 delaunay with polygons lc palette


Here, on the other hand, is the same data plotted using a Gaussian kernel density. Note that this is summing the contribution of nearby points, so the net z value is greater than the original range of z values.  That may or may not capture the property you want. The extent of smoothing may be varied by changing the final two parameters in the set dgrid3d command, which control the x and y distance over which any individual point contributes to the net value.
set dgrid3d 100,100 gauss kdensity 0.5,5.0
set pm3d noborder
set view map
splot 'DATA' with pm3d 



Very complete answer... My data are samples and independent events (collected every ½ hour during a whole month). 3rd column is the difference between two thermometer readings, 1st col. is the wind speed and 2nd col. is the humidity. Delaunay triangulation might be useful since my data often change very rapidly, making approx. always difficult. Even dgrid3d 900,900 might miss something; actually it cannot make it to have colors vary smoothly in 3D. I'm glad that gnuplot 6 performs 2D triangulation, that's already a big jump, at least for contour plots; I'll check that out with contourlabels.

Gnuplot currently performs Delaunay triangulation only for the purpose of generating hulls.  You can capture that step as a set of triangles, as I showed, but the program itself does not use it for other purposes.  So no, it will not affect the generation of contour plots. However you may be overly pessimistic about the effect of the grid size in dgrid3d.  Each point's contribution to the kernel density function depends on its distance in Cartesian space, not on the grid spacing. But it is true that contour generation will miss a peak or valley that lies entirely inside one grid segment.
